# How to generate UML diagrams of an existing project in Visual Studio Enterprise 2022?

Tags: c#, uml, visual-studio-2022, class-diagram

### Question

How to generate UML diagrams of an existing project in Visual Studio Enterprise 2022?

---

### Description

I'm studying a project:
https://github.com/EnLabSoftware/Repository_UnitOfWork_Example

I want to get automatically, for example, a class diagram with associations.
I only get the code map.

**Example**
[image]

### Pictures

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

### Installed products.

Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2022 (2)
Version 17.1.6
VisualStudio.17.Release/17.1.6+32421.90
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.8.04084

Installed version: Enterprise

Visual C++ 2022 00482-10000-00261-AA827
Microsoft Visual C++ 2022

Charting and Architecture Analysis Tools 00482-10000-00261-AA827
Charting and Architecture Analysis Tools (Microsoft)

ADL Tools Service Provider 1.0
This package contains services used by Data Lake tools

ASA Service Provider 1.0

ASP.NET and Web Tools 2019 17.1.363.30963
ASP.NET and Web Tools 2019

ASP.NET Web Frameworks and Tools 2019 17.1.363.30963
For more information, see the website https://www.asp.net/

Azure Data Lake Tools for Visual Studio 2.6.5000.0
Microsoft Azure Data Lake Tools for Visual Studio

Azure Functions and Web Jobs Tools 17.1.363.30963
Azure Functions and Web Jobs Tools

Azure Stream Analytics Tools for Visual Studio 2.6.5000.0
Microsoft Azure Stream Analytics Tools for Visual Studio

Common Azure Tools 1.10
Provides common services for use by Azure Mobile Services and Microsoft Azure Tools.

Cookiecutter 17.0.21344.1
Provides tools for searching, instantiating, and configuring templates in cookiecutter format.

Microsoft Azure Hive Query Language Service 2.6.5000.0
Language service for Hive query

Microsoft Azure Stream Analytics Language Service 2.6.5000.0
Language service for Azure Stream Analytics

Microsoft Azure Tools for Visual Studio 2.9
Support for Azure Cloud Services projects

Microsoft JVM Debugger 1.0
Provides support for connecting the Visual Studio debugger to JDWP compatible Java Virtual Machines

Microsoft Library Manager 2.1.161+abc97ecc7d.RR
Easy installation of client libraries for any web project

Microsoft MI-Based Debugger 1.0
Provides support for connecting Visual Studio to MI compatible debuggers

Python with Pylance 17.0.21344.1
Provides IntelliSense, projects, templates, debugging, interactive windows and other auxiliary functions for Python developers.

Python — Django support 17.0.21344.1
Provides templates and integration for the Django web platform.

Python — profiling support 17.0.21344.1
Profiling support for Python projects.

Razor (ASP.NET Core) 17.0.0.2206201+62a2c1d6162f828801565a7ca26d9d48b81 0a05b
Provides language services for ASP.NET Core Razor.

SQL Server Data Tools 17.0.62203.25080
Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools

ToolWindowHostedEditor 1.0
Hosting json editor into a tool window

Visual Studio IntelliCode 2.2
Development using artificial intelligence for Visual Studio.

Visual F# Tools 17.1.0-beta.21610.4+07b5673e4f2fa7630e78abe37f16b372353a7 242
Microsoft Visual F# Tools

NuGet Package Manager 6.1.0
NuGet Package Manager in Visual Studio. For more information about NuGet, see
the website https://docs.nuget.org/

Tools C# 4.1.0-5.22165.10+e555772db77ca828b02b4bd547c318387f11d01 f
C# components used in the integrated development environment. Depending on  the type and settings of the project, different versions of the compiler can be used.

Visual Basic Tools 4.1.0-5.22165.10+e555772db77ca828b02b4bd547c318387f11d01 f
Visual Basic components used in the integrated development environment.
Depending on the type and settings of the project, different versions of the compiler can be used.

Microsoft Visual C++ 1.0 Wizards Microsoft Visual C++ Wizards

Debugging .NET Core with WSL 1.0
Debugging .NET Core with WSL

Microsoft Visual Studio 1.0 VC Package
Microsoft Visual Studio VC Package

Visual Studio Code 1.0 Debugging Adapter Placement Package
Interaction level for hosting Visual Studio Code debugging adapters in Visual Studio

Snapshot Debugging Extension 1.0
Details about the Visual Studio Snapshot Debugging Extension

Tool Extensions for Visual Studio 1.0 containers
Viewing, diagnosing and managing containers in Visual Studio.

Microsoft Visual Studio Tools for Containers 1.2
Application Development, Launch and Validation ASP.NET Core in the target environment. By pressing the F5 key, you can send the application directly to the container with debugging, and the CTRL+F5 keys allow you to change and update the application without reassembling the container.

TypeScript Tools 17.0.1229.2001
TypeScript Tools for Microsoft Visual Studio

Visual Studio Tools for Containers 1.0
Visual Studio Tools for Containers

Azure Application Service Tools, version 3.0.0 17.1.363.30963
Azure Application Service Tools, version 3.0.0